# Vectorizing Computation from Table Data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have two tables for some values and want to do a matrix calculation with it by Matlab. I know how to do it in scalar and then make a vector by combining these calculated scalar values. The problem description is as follows:

```
Table 1  
in|out|  IMP  |  Ang    
1 | 2 | 0.871 | 0.281
1 | 4 | 0.304 | 0.304
1 | 5 | 0.064 | 0.064
2 | 3 | 0.108 | 0.108
3 | 4 | 0.297 | 0.297
4 | 5 | 0.297 | 0.297
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Table 2
indx|     val  | shift
  1 |   1.0003 | 0.1
  2 |   0.9784 | 0.2
  3 |   1.0019 | 0.09
  4 |   1.0039 | 0.1
  5 |   1.0475 | 0.5
```

The scalar values are calculated this way.
We must get 6 scaler values based 'in' and 'out' at table one. these values are C12,C14,C15,C23,C34,C45, other elements like C35 is 0.
where

```
C12=(1.003/0.871)*(cos(0.281)-0.978*cos(0.281-0.2+0.1)).
```

In other words,

```
C12=(val(1)/IMP(1,2))*(cos(Ang(1,2))-val(2)*cos(Ang(1,2)-shift(2)+shift(1))).
```

I tried to make a matrix using this table. for example I've constructed `IMP_mat` for 3rd column of table 1 (IMP_mat(1,2)=0.871
and so on). But in equations for calculating C12,.. I am getting error as some values for `IMP_mat` are zero as they are not defined in table (for example IMP_mat(1,3)=0).
%% EDIT:
Based on @krisdestruction's suggestion, I have written the code in table format and converted it in matrix form. But I don't know what to do next.

```
in=[1 1 1 2 3 4]';
out=[2 4 5 3 4 5]';
IMP=[0.871 0.304 0.064 0.108 0.297 0.297 ]';
Ang=[0.281  0.304   0.064   0.108   0.297   0.297]';
indx=[ 1    2   3   4   5]';
val=[1.0003 0.9784  1.0019  1.0039  1.0475]';
shift=[0.1  0.2 0.09    0.1 0.5]';
T1=table(in,out,IMP,Ang)
T2=table(indx,val,shift)
M1 = table2array( T1 );
M2 = table2array( T2 );
```

And now, I think the problem description for c12,... becomes more complex. 
Also, it seems using this table thing expend a lot of compution. Is that right?
My actual data have thousands of elements.
%% My Attemp:
I have tried to write them manually in matrix forms and do the calculation. But still I don't know how to vectorize my relationship for C. 
 Here is the script:

```
  %IMP                             %Ang
 IMPmat( 1  ,  2 )=   0.871  ;    Angmat( 1 ,   2 )=    0.281   ; 
 IMPmat( 1   , 4 )=   0.304  ;    Angmat( 1 ,   4 )=    0.304   ;
 IMPmat( 1  ,  5 )=   0.064  ;    Angmat( 1 ,   5 )=    0.064   ;
 IMPmat( 2  ,  3 )=   0.108  ;    Angmat( 2 ,   3 )=    0.108   ;
 IMPmat( 3   , 4 )=   0.297  ;    Angmat( 3 ,   4 )=    0.297   ;
 IMPmat( 4  ,  5 )=   0.297  ;    Angmat( 4 ,   5 )=    0.297   ;

% 
val=[1.0003 0.9784  1.0019  1.0039  1.0475]';
shift=[0.1  0.2 0.09    0.1 0.5]';
%%
C12=(val(1)/IMPmat(1,2))*(cos(Angmat(1,2))-val(2)*cos(Angmat(1,2)-shift(2)+shift(1)))
C14=(val(1)/IMPmat(1,4))*(cos(Angmat(1,4))-val(4)*cos(Angmat(1,4)-shift(4)+shift(1)))
```

%% EDIT(New)
I have tried something else. It gives some results without error. But I am not sure if I calculated correctly. But for the first case, it gives the correct result. Here is my Attempt:

```
  in= [1 1 1 2 3 4]';
  out=[2 4 5 3 4 5]';
  IMP=[0.871    0.304   0.064   0.108   0.297   0.297 ]';
  Ang=[0.281    0.304   0.064   0.108   0.297   0.297]';
  indx=[ 1  2   3   4   5]';
  val=[1.0003   0.9784  1.0019  1.0039  1.0475]';
  shift=[0.1    0.2 0.09    0.1 0.5]';
  C=(val(in)./IMP).*(cos(Ang)-val(out).*cos(Ang-shift(out)+shift(in)))
```

Comment: How should the final output matrix look like? Which errors do you get? Post all the code you already tried so we can build upon that.

Comment: Please let me know if I need to elaborate on my answer. While I can show you calculations using your example, I'm sure you are able to make it work after putting it in matrix form. If not, please let me know and I'll cater the solution or clarify my answer closer to your data.

Comment: I tried to do your suggestion. But still I have some problem. I edited my question and included my attempts within it. Please check the question again. Thank you for your time  @krisdestruction

Comment: @Jamaisavenir You need to use `IMP(out)` instead of `IMP`, otherwise it looks correct and I still suggest you convert it to a matrix.

Comment: @Jamaisavenir Let me know if that fixed your issue and kindly accept my answer if it's correct :)

Comment: Thank you @krisdestruction . But, why should I use `IMP(out)` . As you see in my first post, `C12=(val(1)/IMP(1,2))*(cos(Ang(1,2))-val(2)*cos(Ang(1,2)-shift(2)+shift(1))).` In this equation `IMP(1,2)` is 0.871 (See Table 1). However, If I use `IMP(out)` it gives me `0.304` Because first element of `out` is 2, so first element of IMP(2)=0.304. Please tell me if I am right to not.

Comment: @Jamaisavenir Sorry I meant `IMP(in)` if you want to get the first element of `IMP`. This is due to the fact that `IMP(1)==0.871`. Correct me if I'm wrong about my assumption about the calculation for the other rows.

Comment: For calculating `c12` we need to use `IMP(1,2)` which is `0.871` (Table 1). So as you mentioned we cannot use the new IMP(out) as its value is not `0.871`. But, for calculating `c14` we need to use `IMP(1,4)` (table 1) which is 0.304. but using `IMP (in)` returns `0.871` again which is not useful our case. This happens for that fact that `in=[1 1  1 2 3 4]`, so the second element of `IMP(in)` is again `IMP(1)`.  for calculating `C12` we need `IMP=0.871`, for `C14` we need `IMP= 0.304`, for `C15` we need `IMP=0.064` and ... @krisdestruction

Comment: In that case, it was as I originally suggested. Just feed in the entire `IMP` column vector for vectorization. This works as `0.871` and `0.304` are just the respective elements in the vector. Note you don't need to specify 2 indices in a 1D vector. For a table, you can just reference `T.Var1` where `T` is the table variable and `Var1` is the column name.

Comment: @Jamaisavenir Anytime :) Thanks for the acceptance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do specific operations that can be easily done/vectorized in a matrix. In that case, I would recommend you convert it into a matrix using `table2mat` first and perform your calculation. It's easy because you have all numeric data.

Suppose you have a table formatted like this.

```
Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4
____    ____    ____    ____
1       2       2       1   
1       4       5       5   
1       5       1       3   
2       3       3       7   
3       4       5       5   
4       5       5       5
```

The code to generate is below.

```
T = table([1 1 1 2 3 4]',[2 4 5 3 4 5]',[2 5 1 3 5 5]',[1 5 3 7 5 5]')
```

You can use this line of code to convert it to a matrix array.

```
M = table2array( T );
```

You can then proceed to perform your calculations using matrices and for each of the `C12`,`C14`,`C15`,`C23`,`C34`,`C45` in vector form (if possible).

Then you can use the following line of code to do your calculation.

```
C = val(in) ./ IMP .* cos( Ang(out) ) - val(out) .* cos( Ang(in) - shift(out) + shift(in) );
```

The result is shown here.

```
>> C
C =
    2.1772
    8.2435
    2.1805
   14.3389
    8.2204
    2.2290
```